# Pontryagin principle, Optimal control or Numerical scheme ? logical constraint?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, numerical-optimization, optimal-control, large-deviation-theory

I have  the following optimal control problem :

$ \textit{ Minimize } \qquad J(u,x,T) =\displaystyle \int_0^T \Big[ u_1(t)\log\frac{u_1(t)}{ x_1(t)x_2(t)} - u_1(t) +x_1(t)x_2(t) 
 \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \: u_2(t)\log\frac{u_2(t)}{x_2(t)} - u_2(t) + x_2(t)  \Big] dt$

subject to the dynamic $\displaystyle \qquad 
 \left[\begin{array}{l}      \dot{x}_1(t)\\      \dot{x}_2(t) \end{array}\right]  
=  \left[\begin{array}{rcl}      -u_1(t)&+&u_2(t)\\      u_1(t)&& \end{array}\right]$,

with the constraints

1. $T>0$ is free
2. $x_1(0), x_2(0)$ are fixed, $x_2(T) =0$ but $x_1(T)$ is free.
3. $x_1(t),x_2(t)\geq 0$
4. $u_1(t),u_2(t)\geq 0$
5. $u_1(t) >0 $ only if $x_2(t)x_1(t)>0$
6. $u_2(t) >0 $ only if $x_2(t)>0$

How can we handle constraints $5.$ and $6.$ ? it seems to be logical constraints?

Pontryangin principle could work for this problem? considering constraints $5.$ and $6.$ ?

I didn't found a lecture note or Book  on this kind of problem.

I also want to solve it Numerically, could any one help with a reference?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Numerical shame or numerical scheme?

Comment: Your last two conditions can be reformulated: a) $x_2(t)=0\Rightarrow u_1(t)=u_2(t)=0$, i.e., you stop when you first enter $x_2(t)=0$; b) $x_1(t)=0\Rightarrow u_1(t)=0$, i.e., your solution can have a sort of cusp at $x_1=0$.

Comment: yes of course  Numerical "scheme". Sorry
I want to have a numerical solution since i guess it would be difficult to have a theoretical one.

Comment: Yes it can be formulated as implication.But is it possible to have implications as constraints in optimal control ? any reference please?

Comment: After some closer inspection it seems that the problem does not have a solution. If $x_2(0)>0$ and $u_1\ge 0$, how would you drive $x_2$ towards 0? Otherwise, if $x_2(0)=0$ the above implication says that $u_1=u_2=0$.